# How do I fix my time loop with a nested Jacobi iterative loop?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a program which is time dependent, where it calculates the temperature at each time step via the Jacobian iterative method. However the time-dependent temperature is currently within the spatial convergence leading the temperature to infinity if left alone. I've tried putting it outside the spatial loop but no reasonable plots have been seen. I will attach the code below

```
    # importing kits needed
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
    from matplotlib import cm
    import copy
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D  # <-- Note the capitalization!
    import sys
    import time

    # assigning plot features


    def plot_T_Jacobi(X, Y, Z):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        # Surface plot settings (leave untouched for time being)
        surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
        ax.set_title("2D Heat Variation, Jacobi iterative method")
        ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
        # A StrMethodFormatter is used automatically
        ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')
        # Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
        fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5)
        # fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
        # fig.colorbar(surf)
        plt.xlabel('Distance along X')
        plt.ylabel('Distance along Y')
        plt.show()


# Setting up calculation codes
def grid_position(i, j, Px):
    return (Px) * j + i

start_time = time.time()
# Geometry and mesh settings
E = 0.001
x = 1
y = 1
Nx = 20
Ny = 20
Px = Nx + 1
Py = Ny + 1
hx = x / Nx
hy = y / Ny
k = 0
# Dirichlet BCs
Hup = 0
Hdown = 0
Hright = 0
Hleft = 0
if Hup < 0 or Hdown < 0 or Hright < 0 or Hleft < 0:
    sys.exit('Please check temperature and input values in Kelvin')
max_iterations = 10000
dt = 0.01  # Reduced time step value
total_time = 10
Nt = int(total_time/dt)
X = np.arange(0, x + E, hx)
Y = np.arange(0, y + E, hy)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = copy.deepcopy(Y)
Z[:, :] = 0.0
sol_len = (Px) * (Py)
print('solution size:', sol_len)
M = np.zeros([sol_len, sol_len])
H = np.zeros([sol_len])
T_old = np.zeros([sol_len])
for j in range(Py):
    for i in range(Px):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        M[pos, pos] = ((2 + k / 2) / (hx ** 2)) + ((2 + k / 2) / (hy ** 2)) + (1/dt)
        #H[pos] = 1.

        if i > 0:
            posleft = grid_position(i - 1, j, Px)
            M[pos, posleft] = -0.5 / (hx ** 2) - 0.5 / (hy ** 2)

        if i < Px - 1:
            posright = grid_position(i + 1, j, Px)
            M[pos, posright] = -0.5 / (hx ** 2) - 0.5 / (hy ** 2)

        if j > 0:
            posdown = grid_position(i, j - 1, Px)
            M[pos, posdown] = -0.5 / (hy ** 2) - 0.5 / (hx ** 2)

        if j < Py - 1:
            posup = grid_position(i, j + 1, Px)
            M[pos, posup] = -0.5 / (hy ** 2) - 0.5 / (hy ** 2)
for j in range(int(Py/2)-2,int(Py/2)+3):
    for i in range(int(Px/2)-2,int(Px/2)+3):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        H[pos] = 1
if Hleft > 0:
    i = 0
    for j in range(Py):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        M[pos, pos] = 1e10
        H[pos] = 1e10 * Hleft
if Hright > 0:
    i = Px - 1
    for j in range(Py):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        M[pos, pos] = 1e10
        H[pos] = 1e10 * Hright
if Hdown > 0:
    j = 0
    for i in range(Px):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        M[pos, pos] = 1e10
        H[pos] = 1e10 * Hdown
if Hup > 0:
    j = Py - 1
    for i in range(Px):
        pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
        M[pos, pos] = 1e10
        H[pos] = 1e10 * Hup

n = len(H)
T = np.zeros(n)  # Initialize T with ones for the initial guess

# The Jacobi iteration for each time step
for t in range(Nt):
    T_new = T.copy()  # Create a copy of T for updating the T
    for k in range(max_iterations):  # Number of iterations
        for j in range(Py):
            for i in range(Px):
                pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
                xapprox = H[pos] + (1 / dt) * T[pos]
                if i > 0:
                    posleft = grid_position(i - 1, j, Px)
                    xapprox -= M[pos, posleft] * T[posleft]
                if i < Px - 1:
                    posright = grid_position(i + 1, j, Px)
                    xapprox -= M[pos, posright] * T[posright]
                if j > 0:
                    posdown = grid_position(i, j - 1, Px)
                    xapprox -= M[pos, posdown] * T[posdown]
                if j < Py - 1:
                    posup = grid_position(i, j + 1, Px)
                    xapprox -= M[pos, posup] * T[posup]
                if abs(M[pos, pos]) != 0:
                    T_new[pos] = (1 /(M[pos, pos])) * xapprox

        norm = np.max(np.abs(T - T_new) ** 0.5)
        T = T_new  # Update T with the new T
        if norm < E:
            #print("Converged at iteration", k)
            break
    if norm >= E:
        print("solution doesn't converge within the maximum number of iterations")
    if t%int(Nt/4) == 0:
      Z_new = copy.deepcopy(Y)
      Z_new[:, :] = 0.0
      for j in range(int(Py)):
          for i in range(int(Px)):
              pos = grid_position(i, j, Px)
              Z_new[j, i] = T[pos]
      plot_T_Jacobi(X, Y, Z_new)
```

I've tried storing the old time step's temperature, then adding it on xapprox whilst dividing it by a time step. But it brought no fruitful results.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).